# Java - Multiply Array Values into another Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an `int[]` array with x values (x can be defined by the user), the values are random ints between 1 and 9. Now I want to create another Array with the same amount of values, and each value of the new Array is the product of all values from the other Array, except the same index.

So for example:

- Array1: `{4,3,5,7}`
- Array2: `{3*5*7, 4*5*7, 4*3*7, 4*3*5} = {105, 140, 84, 60}`

Here's what I have:

```
public static int[] multiplyArrayValues (int [] values) {

    int array[] = new int[values.length];

    for (int y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
        array[y] = 1;
    }

    /*for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {      // wrong                        
        for (int z = 0; z < x; z++) {                           
            if (z != i) {                                                   
                array[i] = array[i] * values[z];                                        
            }               
        }           
    }*/

    return array;
}
```

The difficulty is, I have to avoid for-loops in for-loops for performance. Which is why that one block is commented-out.  Dividing is not allowed.

Comment: Is `1` allowed? You can't really "exclude" it from the multiplication result: `{1,1,2,3} => {1*2*3, 1*2*3, 1*1*3, 1*1*2} = {6, 6, 3, 2}`

Comment: @SimonKraemer the numbers are random and just atm between 1 and 9. later on, negative numbers and / or user input will be added. So yes, 1 is allowed, even if it changes nothing when you leave it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's more a question about the algorithm to use. You can multiply all the numbers of the original array, lets call this `p`. Now the number at position `i` in the new array is `p / values[i]`.

If you must not use division, you can set up two temporary arrays, one contains the product of the values with smaller or equal index, the other the product of the values with larger or equal index.

```
s[i] = product of v[j] where j <= i
l[i] = product of v[j] where j >= i
```

both arrays can be set up with a simple loop each.

Now you can calculate `array[i]` as `s[i-1] * l[i+1]`, taking special care of the border values. This needs also just a simple loop.

Using these ideas and doing some optimizations leads to the following code

```
public static int[] multiplyArrayValues (int [] values) {
    int[] a = new int[values.length];
    int p = 1;
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        a[i] = p;
        p *= values[i];
    }
    p = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        a[i] *= p;
        p *= values[i];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I think to get complete answer to this interview question you should pack  s/l into source/destination array pair (should be possible to fill destination going forward and corrupt source going backward). OP should ask interviewer if extra arrays are allowed and whether corrupting source is ok.

Answer (score 2):

First multiply all the elements from the array. And then loop over all elements and divide the previously computed multiplication with current item.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply all numbers and save it a variable(say product) , now iterate over the array using single loop and divide the product by number at each index(product/a[i]).

But since you are using integer , if the size of array is huge and also the array values is big , the product might overflow int.

Consider using Big integer i would say.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    static int[] multiplyArrayValues(int[] values) {
        int product = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            product *= values[i];
        }
        int[] result = new int[values.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = product / values[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void testMultiplyArrayValues(int[] values)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values) + " => " + Arrays.toString(multiplyArrayValues(values)));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testMultiplyArrayValues(new int[] {1,1,2,3});
        testMultiplyArrayValues(new int[] {4,3,5,7});
        testMultiplyArrayValues(new int[] {9,9,9,9});
        testMultiplyArrayValues(new int[] {1,1,1,1});
        testMultiplyArrayValues(new int[] {1,2,3,4});
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3] => [6, 6, 3, 2]
[4, 3, 5, 7] => [105, 140, 84, 60]
[9, 9, 9, 9] => [729, 729, 729, 729]
[1, 1, 1, 1] => [1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4] => [24, 12, 8, 6]
```

If the range of possible values changes you might want to change the data types of `product` and the return value of `multiplyArrayValues`.
Also there is no check for the values being negative or invalid. Zero will lead to a crash.

Comment: since dividing is not allowed, I can't use your solution, but it would work, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with java stream API

```
 private static List<Integer> multiply(List<Integer> inputArray) {

    return inputArray.stream()
            .map(item ->
                    inputArray.stream()
                            .reduce(1, (a, b) -> {
                                if (item.equals(b))
                                    return a;
                                return a * b;
                            }))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or one liner

```
  private static List<Integer> multiply(List<Integer> inputArray) {
    return inputArray.stream().map(e -> (inputArray.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> e.equals(b) ? a : a * b))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

and explenation:

lets imagine that array as input data

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(2, 3, 5);
```

Then let's decompose the first scenario with '2', in the end, should be '15' (3*5)

```
// a = 1, a is identity (preassigned value '1' in our case - reduce(1,)...;
// 1. e = 2 - first element of the array;
// 2. e = 2, a = 1,b = 2 (first value of the array); e == b ? yes then a = a (1)
// 3. e = 2, a = 1,b = 3 (second value of array); e == b? no a * b = 1 * 3 = 3
// 4. e = 2, a = 3, b = 5 (third value of the array); e = b? no  a* b = 5 * 3 = 15
```